# How to change the separator on the clock?

Tags: time, clock

I'm having the following problem:
I've set the (Language Support) - Regional Formats (Display numbers etc.) to Hungarian, the format should be the following:

Example:

Number: 1.234.567,89

Date: 2016. nov 6, vasárnap (name of the day, not relevant, here's the relevant part:) 10:15:15

My clock however, isn't separated by `:`, but by `.`.

So my clock displays 9.20.46 atm., instead of 9:20:46.

Setting the format back to English would probably solve my issue, but doesn't anyone know how to modify this one instead, in order for it to be separated by colons instead of dots?
Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: It's not even similar to that one.

Comment: How and why? You wanted to change the time format the question was too... How is this different?

Comment: I don't want to change the time format, what I want to change is the separator, from '.' to ':'.

Comment: Separator is part of the time format.

Comment: If I'd be a Ubuntu expert, I wouldn't be asking questions. Also, that question is for a totally different Ubuntu version than mine. Thanks for your effort, but sadly that doesn't really help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the date format](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43999/how-to-change-the-date-format)

Comment: Sorry for all this. I mean ^this is the duplicate target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change time format in Ubuntu 15.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/628943/how-to-change-time-format-in-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can archive it by creating a custom locale in:

```
/usr/share/i18n/locales
```

Modify the date format using [ASCII CODE](http://asciitable.com/) (Change from `U002E` to `U003A`). 
Compile it using `localedef` 
Direct `LC_TIME` to your custom locale, restart pc.

For more info: [How to Change Date Formats on Ubuntu](https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks, this makes lots of sense actually, yet for some reason, my locale remains the old one, even though I've set the LC_TIME to the custom one I've just modified. Even modified the original one, and compiled it afterwards, yet the format remained the same. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Had to install "dconf", and set the time-format manually to the custom made one. (com/canonical/indicator/datetime, if anyone ever has the same issue)